# How to unhide rows based on the value in the target range?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written code that first hides a range and is then supposed to unhide the relevant rows based on the value in the target range.

The hide is working, but my code doesn't unhide anything:

```vb
Sub Hide(row As Double, dExtras As Double)
    'Hide rij op basis van argument
    Rows(row & ":" & row + dExtras).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub

Sub Unhide(row As Double, dExtras As Double)
    'Unhide rij op basis van argument
    Rows(row & ":" & row + dExtras).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

The code that calls these subs:

```vb
Sub AlertsShowHide()

    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lAantalAlerts As Long

    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    With wsTemplate

        lAantalAlerts = .Range("aantalAlerts")
    
        'Hide all
        .Range(.Range("aantalAlerts").Offset(2, 0), .Range("antVoorgaandeAlerts").Offset(-3, 0)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
        'Unhide relevant alerts
        For i = 1 To lAantalAlerts

        'Unhide in/out/voeding rows
            Call AlertsRow(.Range("antEachAlertType" & CStr(i)))
        
        'Only works up to 6 alerts
            If i = 6 Then Exit For

        Next i
    
    'Unhide extra room for process more than 6 alerts
        If lAantalAlerts > 6 Then
            Call Unhide(.Range("antAlertToelicht7").row, 0)
            MsgBox "Bij meer dan 6 alerts handmatig de beschrijving toevoegen van deze extra alerts onderaan bij vakje 'Toelichting MEER DAN 6 alerts'", vbOKOnly, "Veel alerts"
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub


Sub AlertsRow(target As Range)
    'Unhide de relevant rijen Inkomnde, Uitgaande en/of voeding afhankelijk van gekozen alert(s)

    ' Hide all
    Call Hide(target.Offset(1, 0).row, 58)
    
    ' Unhide header
    Call Unhide(target.Offset(-3, 0).row, 3)
    
    ' Unhide toelichting
    Call Unhide(target.Offset(57, 0).row, 2)
    
   'Determine which alerts to unhide
    If target.Value Like "*WWFT*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(1, 0).row, 3)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Credit on Card*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(5, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Funding*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(8, 0).row, 1)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Crypto & Trading*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(10, 0).row, 3)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Gambling*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(14, 0).row, 3)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Money transfer*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(18, 0).row, 3)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*P2P*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(22, 0).row, 3)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Passing through*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(26, 0).row, 3)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Activation of a dormant account*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(30, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Cash*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(33, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Donations*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(36, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*High Risk Terrorism Activities*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(39, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*High Risk Terrorism Countries*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(42, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Sanction High Risk Offshore*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(45, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Smurfen*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(48, 0).row, 2)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Transfer to bank account*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(51, 0).row, 1)
    End If
    If target.Value Like "*Trx on card*" Then
        Call Unhide(target.Offset(54, 0).row, 2)
    End If

End Sub
```

I added a watch to the target value, to see if this is correct. Which it is. So it seems the `Unhide()` sub is not working.
However when I try hard coding with this sub, it does work.

Comment: You call `AlertsRow` in a loop, but every time it runs it calls `Hide(target.Offset(1, 0).row, 58)` so it basically hides anything it might have unhidden previously?

Comment: In your `AlertsRow` procedure your target possibilities appear to be mutually exclusive - if so then it would make sense to use a series of 'ElseIf` constructs because, as written, _all_ of your `If``tests are evaluated, i.e. even after finding a 'match'

Comment: @TimWilliams I've already tried to run it without that line, however I still get the same results. So it looks like it has something to do with `.Range(.Range("aantalAlerts").Offset(2, 0), .Range("antVoorgaandeAlerts").Offset(-3, 0)).EntireRow.Hidden = True` in the `AlertShowHide` procedure. I just can't figure out what as this is called outside of the loop

Comment: @SpectralInstance I've tried this, it sadly does not work

Comment: `ElseIf` is anything but an esoteric construct - if it doesn't work then your possibilities must _not_ be mutually exclusive... btw `target.Row + 1` would be more efficient than `target.Offset(1,0).Row` etc.

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem might be without knowing what all of the named ranges correspond to.  Can you replace those with static ranges so we can see where those ranges are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue may well be one of 'scope' - you have been vary careful in the main procedure `AlertsShowHide()` only to use explicitly-qualified `Range` references, and the fact that you specifically target the *Template* worksheet raises the possibility that it isn't necessarily the active sheet when your code runs.

Your `Hide()` and `Unhide()` procedures, on the other hand, use only numeric arguments and unqualified `Range` references, meaning that they will operate on whatever the active sheet happens to be at the time of execution. I propose re-factoring both of these procedures as follows

```
Sub Hide(start As Range, dExtras As Long)
    'Hide rij op basis van argument
    start.Resize(dExtras).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Unhide(start As Range, dExtras As Long)
    'Hide rij op basis van argument
    start.Resize(dExtras).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

by passing an argument of type `Range` you are implicitly 'telling' the procedure on *which* worksheet you want to do the hiding or un-hiding.

Taking as examples the first 2 calls from your `AlertsRow()` procedure, you would call the re-factored procedures thus

```
Call Hide(target.Offset(1, 0), 58)

' Unhide header
Call Unhide(target.Offset(-3, 0), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

(this is not answer to your problem) Use one Sub for hide and Show and parameters Long not Double:

```
Sub ShowOrHide(row As Long, hideflag As Boolean, dExtras As Long)
    'Hide rij op basis van argument
    Rows(row & ":" & row + dExtras).EntireRow.Hidden = hideflag
End Sub
```